# Recursive Directory Searching PHP with Regex

Tags: php, regex, search, recursion, directory

beWhat if I needed to recursively search some directories in order to find a .something file?

I have this code so far:

```
   $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/');
   $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

   foreach ($iterator as $filename) {
     if(strpos($filename, ".apk")){
         $page->addToBody(substr($filename, 2)."</br>");
         $filename = substr($filename, 2);  
     }
   }
```

This works in returning the only .apk file in the directories, however I want to be able to find a specific file if more than one are found.

e.g. I want to say find all the filesnames that contain "hello" and end in .apk.

With Glob() i did this which worked great:

```
glob('./'path'/*{'Hello'}*.apk',GLOB_BRACE);
```

However its not recursive. and depends on the correct directory being specified. 
Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: Hmz... 1. If you are on a linux machine, you can take advantage of the os functions! 2. If there's a directory called "hello" should all files within be returned? 3. You said regex, but your code uses strpos. Which do you actually want/need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of strpos() you can use a regular expression like:

```
[...]
if(preg_match('/.*hello.*\.apk$/', $filename))
[...]
```

This example represents "*hello*.apk". So a string that has "hello" somewhere in it and ends with ".apk".

See [PHP preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for further information.

Comment: So could you add extra search fields to the regular expression? e.g. find a file name that has hello, abc, test and ends in .apk.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
if(strpos($filename, ".apk"))
```

To:

```
if (preg_match('@hello.*\.apk$@', $filename))
```

While regular expressions are more flexible, you can still use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) along with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
if (strpos($filename, 'hello') !== false && substr($filename, -4) === '.apk')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching both:

```
if(strpos($filename, ".apk") !== false && strpos($filename, "Hello") !== false){
```

The !== false is necessary, otherwise Hello.apk will not be returned